# What do these C++ functions return? ClassA*& func1()

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Hi all to experts in programming C/C++ code.
I stumbled upon this code, but I'm confused what the 2 functions are returning.
Any kind souls could help me out?
I've tried to make the code as generic & useful to others as possible.

```
ClassA*& func1() {
    static ClassA* mClassA;
    return mClassA;
}

ClassA* func2() {
    ClassA*& mClassA = func1();
    if(!mClassA) {
        ... // omitted some code that fill mClassA with data.
    }
    return mClassA;
}
```

[edit] Also wanted to ask, do the *& in func1() and func2() cancel each other out?

Comment: It should be noted that it does not make any sense to return a reference to a pointer, rather than returning the pointer itself. And  returning pointers to private data is already bad practice to begin with.

Comment: Removed every mentioning of C in topic and tags, since C does not have references as they are used in this question.

Comment: @Lundin reference to pointer is IMO here important because pointer is probably assigned here in func2(). Other solution would be to return pointer to pointer.

Comment: In general, read types from right to left: "reference to pointer to `ClassA`".

Comment: @luskan I really don't see why. If you for some strange reason need to expose private variables to the outside world ("I'll treat privates as public"), but not want the caller to be able to change them ("wait, maybe these are private after all"), you should either return a const pointer or a direct reference to the object. I don't see how a combination of those two methods would make sense. Whenever one ends up writing obscure things like this, it is in 9 out of 10 cases a clear indication of a flawed program design.

Comment: @Ludin this code is a singleton idiom, normally you would write ClassA& func1() { static ClassA mClassA; return mClassA; }, and this is preferred way since c++11 it is threadsafe. In this case pointers are used to implement some kind of mysterious initialization pattern, code is omitted so we will never know. I suppose func1() is only used in func2(), and func2() is used all over the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ClassA*& func1()
```

returns the static pointer declared inside the method by reference. Doing:

```
ClassA*& x = func1()
x = NULL
```

would alter `mClassA`.

```
ClassA* func2()
```

returns a copy of the pointer. It will point to the same memory, but changing the pointer doesn't affect `mClassA`.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell:

- `func1` provides a singleton pointer.
- `func2` provides a singleton object of type `ClassA`, using the singleton pointer from `func1` as an implementation device.

You can achieve a similar goal more elegantly like this:

```
ClassA & getA()
{
    static ClassA impl = initialize_A();  // Or a lambda or just a constructor.
    return impl;
}
```

This will also clean up the implementation instance at program end, in the correct order, without the need for manual destruction.

Comment: it's not the same, since like this you can not destruct the object

Comment: @BЈовић: Basically: Manual lifetime -> pointer; permanent lifetime -> static.

Answer (score 0):

`func1()` returns a reference to a pointer; in practice, this means that it returns the same pointer that is used inside the function, instead of a copy to it. This way, if you change the value of the pointer (as opposed to changing the value of the object pointed by it), you actually change the value of the pointer inside your function.

This is what makes `func2()` work correctly. It takes a reference to the static pointer `mClassA` inside `func1()` and updates its value if necessary, then returns a copy of the pointer; this is, a pointer pointing to the same address as `mClassA`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ClassA*& func1() {
    static ClassA* mClassA;
    return mClassA;
}
```

`func1()` is kind of a Meyer's singleton. It is similar to creating a global pointer. So, this function creates a pointer "object", and provides full access to it, meaning you can do things like this :

```
func1() = new ClassA;
```

`func2()` just returns a copy of a pointer. That means you can not change it<sup>*</sup> like above.

<sup>* It is possible to change the pointed object by using placement new.</sup>